# What does actually Java stream reduce if only one of BinaryOperator argument is got summarized with itself?

Tags: java, java-stream

Take a look onto the code below: here in binary operator we have reduce((x,y)->x+x). Why it is actually calculated to Optional[512]? I have no explanation.

```
System.out.println((Stream.generate(()->1d).limit(10).
            peek((doubleValue)->{
                System.out.println("Call the first peek: "+doubleValue);
            }).
            reduce((x,y)->x+x)));
```

And here is the output: just to clarify to you I show the individual x are 1.0 in peek section.

```
Call the first peek: 1.0
Call the first peek: 1.0
Call the first peek: 1.0
Call the first peek: 1.0
Call the first peek: 1.0
Call the first peek: 1.0
Call the first peek: 1.0
Call the first peek: 1.0
Call the first peek: 1.0
Call the first peek: 1.0
Optional[512.0]
```

So the question, what governs reduce to work until Optional[512] will be obtained?

Comment: I just checking how x+x should manifest itself in BinaryOperator

Comment: peek output was ok for me, the Optional value was under the question

Comment: You can see how your reduce function is being called by printing its arguments: `.reduce((x, y) -> {System.out.println("x="+x+", y="+y);  return x+x;})))`

Comment: @ernest_k thanks for the printing idea shared with me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you have 10 arguments, but operations is 9. 2^9 = 512

Comment: Thanks @ZhenyaM, so it aggregates it even without y usage?

Comment: @IlyaYevlampiev consider your reduce as this `(1,1) -> 1+1 ... (2,1) -> 2+2 .... (256,1) -> 256+256`

Comment: @IlyaYevlampiev `y` represents next element of stream, where `x` represents an old reduce result. Thus, in your case - yes, ignore

Answer (score 2):

Technically, Stream reduce does not offer to do anything consistent when you do that.

Guarantees are only given with associative reducing operations, and yours isn't (it accounts for first operand and ignores the second.)

When testing your code, you're observing results.

These results are not in any way surprising when trying to make an educated guess about how reduction is implemented in nonparallel streams. However, these results are in no way guaranteed by the documentation of Stream, as you didn't respect the requirements.

For example, the result could have been 1 or 2. Though a little puzzling it would still make sense, and you're the one not meeting the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what's happening here:

```
    System.out.println((Stream.generate(()->1d).limit(10).
            reduce((x,y)-> {
                double ret = x+x;
                System.out.println(ret);
                return ret;
            })));
```

The output is

```
2.0
4.0
8.0
16.0
32.0
64.0
128.0
256.0
512.0
Optional[512.0]
```

Because you have 10 arguments in your stream provided to the [reduce](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) with a default start value `0`.

Since you are using `(x, y) -> x+x` and you are actually doubling the the result over 9 times as `result <- result + result` after the first where `result <- 0 + 1` as @ZhenyaM mentioned: `2^9 = 512`